# Swagger UI not being protected by basic authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a WebApi project that generates OpenApi Swagger doc. The project already uses OIDC authentication. I need to add Basic authentication to the swagger doc, so I followed this [link](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/securing-swagger-in-production-92d0a045a5).

I have the following swagger config in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseSwaggerAuthorized();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API");
    }
    else
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/myapp/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API");
    }

    c.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems["syntaxHighlight"] = new Dictionary<string, object> {
        ["activated"] = false
    };

    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

And I added the following class:

```
public class SwaggerBasicAuthMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public SwaggerBasicAuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IOptions<List<SwaggerCredential>> credentials)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/swagger") ||
            context.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().Contains("index.html"))
        {
            var authHeader = (string)context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic "))
            {
                var header = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authHeader);
                var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(header.Parameter);
                var credential = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes).Split(':');
                var username = credential[0];
                var password = credential[1];

                var current = credentials.Value.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username.Equals(username));
                if (current != null && current.Password.Equals(password))
                {
                    await next(context);
                    return;
                }
            }

            context.Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"] = "Basic";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        }
        else
        {
            await next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

In development, I access my site at: `https://localhost:44333` and the swagger at: `https://localhost:44333/index.html`.

In production, the site is accessed at: 'https://example.com/myapp' and the swagger at: `https://example.com/myapp/index.html`

The dialog to enter credentials is displayed and I enter them. However, the dialog keeps reappearing.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you check if username and password is really getting validated.

Comment: Did you hit a breakpoint `SwaggerBasicAuthMiddleware.InvokeAsync()`?

Comment: @SebastianS. InvokeAsync is always being hit. The problem is that the Authentication header is always missing even after I entered username and password.

Comment: is it load balanced?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander No. Runs in IIS / (IIS Express in VS)

Comment: How do you use OIDC authentication? Maybe it is intercepting the call and clearing the headers.

Comment: @BrunoCanettieri The first response from the server has 3 headers (authenticate, negotiate, ntlm). The second response has just 2 (negotiate, ntlm). Could it be this the problem?

Comment: I have made a new simple project using builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddNegotiate(); and using the SwaggerBasicAuthMiddleware, is not necessary to install swagger, just add /swagger at the end of the url so the middleware can act. When self hosting the Authorization header is visible on the middleware, but when using IIS, the header disappears. My guess is that IIS removes the header if you are using Negotiate, probably for some security reason. I couldn't locate a quick way to go around it, and would have to know more about how you are using authentication to continue.

Comment: Actually, i just realized that I don't understand your motivation, the page should already be secured by the OIDC. If you want to secure for only some users or groups that isn't the way to do it. May I suggest that you use an api key to validate the calls? Check out https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/